# Why was my short answer deleted, but slightly longer answers were not?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-answers

The question is here: [Is $(function() { }) an exact equivalent to $(document).ready(function() { })](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12605972/1689607)

And it boiled down to this:

> "Now, the question is: Is `$(function() { })` an exact equivalent to `$(document).ready(function() { })`?"

---

My deleted answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12605991/1689607

And it directly answered the question:

> "No difference. Exactly the same..............."

---

Other answers were longer, but the answer to the question was ultimately the same. So why was my short *(but entirely on-topic and correct)* answer singled out by a moderator?

The reasons given by the link provided do not apply to my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things regarding your issue:

1. A moderator deleted your answer due to flags on the post.  Your 'answer' didn't add anything to the question that hadn't already been answered, and it wasn't even useful enough to post as a comment.  You may not agree with the deletion, but understand that if you had provided a useful answer *we would not be having this discussion*. Other answers were likely not deleted because there weren't flags on them.  Since most moderator actions take place in the context of the moderator queue (and not the question page), it's not a stretch to believe that the moderator didn't see the other nearly bad answer on the question.
2. Arguing with users in comments is seldom the best way to find out *why* something happened (as was the case before I purged the comments).  You may not agree with the action taken, but the top voted answer to this question shows you why the community feels like your answer should have been deleted.

Finally,

If you have an issue with *any* of the steps taken either in this question or the deletion of your Stack Overflow answer, I invite you to send an email to `team@stackoverflow.com`. They handle all moderator complaints.

Comment: +1 at least for the relative thoughtfulness. Regarding point **1**, mine was the only answer when posted, and was on-topic and correct. This is the basis of my confusion. If someone didn't like it, they should DV it. I'd think a mod would ignore invalid flags, but your comment *"...moderator actions take place in the context of the moderator queue..."* adds clarity. I'll consider that a sufficient answer. Regarding point **2**, I was only trying to respond to the insults and misinformation. I was surprised and disappointed by the vitriolic tone from @meagar, still visible in his answer.

Answer (score 14):

Your short answer was awful.

<strike>If you can't come up with enough content to meet the minimum length requirements, you should **not post**. Don't spam garbage characters into your answers to meet the length requirements.</strike>

It is never appropriate to post ".............." as part of an answer or anywhere else. There is literally no situation in the English language when this is appropriate. Your answers on Stack Overflow should read like words of *reference*, not forum postings.

If you need something to fill the space, why not link to a more authoritative source than your own statement? Your answer is more or less useless without something to back it up. As it stands, your answer was far better suited to a comment, since it seems to be you voicing your subjective opinion.

You'll notice that the top-voted and accepted answer contains more than four words *and* links to the documentation backing up the answer.

Comment: Why is the second paragraph crossed out?

Answer (score 11):

Because. It wasn't that useful.........